# Python: automate typewrite(word) into an input function and hit "enter"

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm using Python 3.7 with pyautogui and have to use an input function to enter a URL from a list.

I have the list in csv format and the code loops through that list to retrieve each URL that must be passed into the input.

I cannot simply pass the string into a url variable because the site I am trying to access blocks my code.

However, the site does not block me when I pass the string into input().

My problem is twofold:

1. The input function doesn't work properly with typewrite(word) passed in.
2. I can't programmatically hit 'enter' once the input box is filled.

   Code snippet:

```
    import csv
    from pyautogui import press, typewrite, hotkey


    urllist = csv.reader(open('Looper.csv'))

    for row in urllist:
        for char in row:
            url = input(typewrite(''.join(char)))
            #Do stuff
```

Comment: I don't understandwhat you try to do with this `input()` - if you want to assign value to variable then simply use `url = row`.

Comment: Yes I know it seems a little strange, but the problem is I have to use an input function so that it "appears" to be a human input...When I just set url = row, my the website blocks my access.

Comment: `typewrite()` is for sending text to *other programs* - sending text to yourself, or indeed using `input()` at all here, makes no sense.  Just assign the value to `url`.

Comment: BTW: argument in `input()` is used to display on screen and input gets it as one string at once, not as chars with delays.

Comment: BTW: `input()` get text at once (after pressing ENTER) so typing text make no sence because `input()` will no see that it was typed.

Comment: @jasonharper I have edited the original post to explain why I can't just pass the string into a variable and use that. The site I'm trying to access redirects me to a captcha which complicates things.

Comment: @furas Please see above.

Comment: as @jasonharper already said - to type in this `input()` you would have to run `pyautogui` in second script which would have to find window which wait for text, focus on it and then send text to this window (with `ENTER` at the end) and this window will send it to input.

Comment: typing text in `input()` can't unblock web page - maybe you simply get different text from file then text which you type in input. You should compare text from file with text which you typed in input to find problem. And first check `print(row)`

Comment: @furas When I do not use input() I am redirected to a captcha. I am not redirected to a captcha when I use input(). Finding a solution for using input() seems simpler than dealing with the captcha.

Comment: If it's some (unspecified) website that you're trying to type this text into, why do you have an `input()` in Python at all?  That's not where you want the text to go...

Comment: @jasonharper I'm not typing into the website, I'm scraping it. I'm only getting a response when I pass the url (using urllib and beautifulsoup) through input().

Comment: `input()` doesn't care how fast you type, or what delays you make between chars. It sends typed text to code as one string. SO your problem is that in file you have text differen then text you type in `input()` - it can be even `\n` at the end of line. OR you get row and convert to string but you should get one element from row - ie. `row[0]`. So you should first check `print(url)` to see what you use as `url` when you get it from file. You could also check `print( url == input() )` to compare text from file with text which you type in input.

Answer (score 0):

If the site blocked your request or send you a captcha but it works with `input()` statement, you should try the `time.sleep` statement.

```py
import time
import csv
from pyautogui import press, typewrite, hotkey


urllist = csv.reader(open('Looper.csv'))

for row in urllist:
    for char in row:
        url = row
        #Do stuff 
        time.sleep(1) # Stops the process for a second
```

This Statement stops processing the function for a second. It could simulate a human user sending this requests...